# How to listen for mouse clicks on table header of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

How to listen for mouse clicks on table header of `JTable`?

If I do like this

```
    getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                //fireOpenActionPerformed();
                openActionCascade.actionPerformed(null);
            }
        }
    });
```

the I can't know which column was clicked when in handler.

Comment: single or double click?

Answer (score 2):

> "the I can't know which column was clicked when in handler."

What about [`JTableHeader#columnAtPoint(Point point)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html#columnAtPoint%28java.awt.Point%29)? (i.e. MouseEvent.getPoint)

> Returns the index of the column that point lies in, or -1 if it lies out of bounds